# Running JUnit Tests in a Swing GUI using Swing Worker

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, junit, swingworker

I'm writing a GUI that is able to perform some JUnit Tests and to handle this I have used a SwingWorker.

When I start the program the GUI comes up and I click through some selections and the SwingWorker initiates and does it's part and finally outputs either a console output or file output. Then I would click through the GUI again and start another test. At this point when the program finishes it would generate the final output twice, e.g. the console output would be followed directly by an identical console output.

I am assuming this is due to the SwingWorker not terminating and "dying".

Also I am creating the SwingWorker when I click a "start" button in the GUI. Is this a bad idea and what would the proper way to do it be instead?

**EDIT** Added code sample

```
public class TestMainFrame {

private static JFrame frame;
private static JTextArea textArea;

public TestMainFrame(){
    createAndShowGUI();
}

private void createAndShowGUI() {
    frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JButton btn = new JButton("Test Me");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(btn.getText().equals("Test Me")){
                testMe();
            }
        }
    });

    textArea = new JTextArea("This is a test pane! \n");
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    frame.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private static void testMe(){
    writeToTextArea("Button Pressed");
    writeToTextArea("Starting tests");

    SwingWorker<Result, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Result, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Result doInBackground() {     
            writeToTextArea("Inside the doInBackground method of SwingWorker");

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void done() {
            writeToTextArea("The SwingWorker has finished");

        }
    };

    worker.execute();
}

private static void writeToTextArea(String text){
    textArea.append(text + "\n");
}
```

Comment: You've got a bug in code that you're not showing us. For best help, create and post your [mcve]. This is not a full code dump but rather a new small program that illustrates your problem for us. I will bet that in your effort to create your [mcve], you'll discover your error.

Comment: Updated the question with a code sample

Comment: I don't know about others, but I will have a difficult time analyzing this without your posting a fully compliant [mcve]. Please read the link.

Comment: My guess -- you're adding the ActionListener multiple times to the button, but hell if I can tell by the post above. Where exactly and how do you add the ActionListener to your button? Do you do it within the `writeStartingTest()` method?

Comment: Nah. The writeStartingTest() method simply outputs a string into a console window. The actionlistener for the button is added before the method/function that I posted above. So whenever the actionListener for the button is clicked and the "text" on the button says "start" the posted piece of code above is run. The button itself works as intended.

As I mentioned I believe it has something to do with e SwingWorker not "ending" it's lifecycle. But I will read the link you attached and update my questions again to fit that style.

Comment: Okay. I updated the code to fit your suggested format.

Comment: Your code works (after changing Result to Void), but it does not duplicate your problem, at least not for me. Also you shouldn't write to a JTextArea from within `doInBackground`.

Comment: To be frank I don't see the my problem appearing in this piece of code however. I guess it could have something to do with the fact that I'm not running the JUnit tests that I do in my original code.

Ofc not, I just had to see if that code snippet was actually run.

Comment: May I ask how you ran the code? Created a "SwingUtilities.invokerLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { new TestMainFrame(); } });?

Answer (score 2):

(Not an answer)
This is how I ran your code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestMainFrame {

   private static JFrame frame;
   private static JTextArea textArea;

   public TestMainFrame() {
      createAndShowGUI();
   }

   private void createAndShowGUI() {
      frame = new JFrame("Test");
      frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      final JButton btn = new JButton("Test Me");
      btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (btn.getText().equals("Test Me")) {
               testMe();
            }
         }
      });

      textArea = new JTextArea("This is a test pane! \n");
      textArea.setEditable(false);
      JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(textArea);

      frame.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

      frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }

   private static void testMe() {
      writeToTextArea("Button Pressed");
      writeToTextArea("Starting tests");

      SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
         @Override
         public Void doInBackground() {
            writeToTextArea("Inside the doInBackground method of SwingWorker");

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public void done() {
            writeToTextArea("The SwingWorker has finished");
         }
      };

      worker.execute();
   }

   // *** note change *** 
   private static void writeToTextArea(final String text) {
      if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
         textArea.append(text + "\n");
      } else {
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               textArea.append(text + "\n");
            }
         });
      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            TestMainFrame testMainFrame = new TestMainFrame();
            testMainFrame.createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried implementing a simple JUnit test in the above code and it works flawless. So I guess it is something wrong with my 3rd party tool. I will have to look into that.

Comment: @Zeliax: I still fear a hidden bug in your code. Consider using a debugger with break points to see what is going on.

Comment: I found the bugger! Thanks for the suggestion of using a debugger. I had a friend look at the code and it immediate became clear to him what could be wrong which resulted in me finding the actual problem. The SwingWorker and the Thread (something I worked on earlier) both succeeded without trouble, and it became clear that I had a global instantiated ArrayList that I appended to every time I ran the JUnit Test.  This ofc resulted in the list growing linearly. I moved the instantiation of the ArrayList to the constructor of the JUnit test and it is now working flawlessly. Thank you!

Comment: @Zeliax: glad you've got things fixed.